# How can I limit search results by the number of tags?

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, tag-filters

Is there a way to search for questions that only have a specific number of tags? Something like `[alpha] tags:1` would be helpful for filtering by tag rather than using `[alpha] -[beta] -[chi] -[delta] -[epsilon]`.

Answer (score 3):

Irritation finally prevailed over inertia, so I generalized an existing query in Data Explorer:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142695/questions-with-only-one-tag

to this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142621/filter-questions-by-a-single-tag-name

And created another:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158468/filter-questions-by-two-tag-names

Answer (score 2):

We don't support this case in search, it's a pretty narrow use case that'd require some indexing changes so it doesn't make sense to support it.

That being said, if you had to *extremely* good use case we'll definitely entertain the idea...but I'm having trouble picturing a scenario.

Comment: It'd extremely useful for cleaning up crap tags and questions... for instance if a question is tagged solely [tag:performance] then you know that there's almost certainly something wrong with the question.

Comment: Also, it would be useful for finding questions within your range of expertise, without the signal/noise ratio that currently exists when using two or three positive tags as a search query, and twice as many negative tags as a filter.

Comment: Nick, can't you slightly change the logic of the favorite/ignored tags so that if tag appears both as ignored and as favorite, the favorite wins? This way I can add `*` to ignored tags and the single tag as favorite and goal achieved.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I moderate [gis.se] where we sometimes get "pure Python" questions more suited to [so] asked.  We are happy to answer questions related to GIS Python libraries but not "pure Python".  I would like to be able to search for questions tagged only with `python`.